# Scrolling element invisible in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I have a problem with a news ticker in Firefox - the scrolling element becomes invisible when animating - and some weird behaviours are occurring:

- When static, the element is displaying well, but when animating it is becoming invisible.
- When mousing over the scrolling element it becomes visible, when mousing out it becomes invisible again.
- When opening the "Inspector" window in Firefox, to look over the code, the element becomes visible. When closing the "Inspector" window, it becomes invisible.
- Replicated the exact code in JSFiddle and the problem is not occurring when testing in Firefox.

I have looked over the code and I have made tests but I cannot find the source of this problem.

In all other browsers everything is working well, only in Firefox this weird behaviour is happening.

Edit:

- It seems to be a local issue happening only on my end.
- Removed links.

Comment: Indeed how can we test this behaviour?

Comment: @AWolff Have you tested the ticker link in Firefox ?

Comment: I have taken into consideration that it may be a bug in my Firefox browser so I have reinstalled my browser and the problem still occurred. I have also used a virtual machine onto which I installed Firefox and tested and still there was a problem. So I presumed that it was not an issue with my copy. If other people are not having this problem, then it must be something else on my end but I don't see what it could be.